# Inside a landscape page content moving up when textbox get focused and SIP is on

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working in windows phone 7. Inside a landscape page content moving up when textbox get focused and  SIP is on.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behavior when text box is focused. Your content is moving up when on screen keyboard is appearing.

if you want your content to stay on it's place you can try to use Coding4fun controls(download with sample here: http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets). Run Test Application, go to Promts -> Basic input or Advanced input.